# VBA HTML Scraping - '.innertext' from complex table

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

All,

I've created the following Module to scrape a single value (1m % change in London house prices) from the below address:

https://www.hometrack.com/uk/insight/uk-cities-house-price-index/

The specific value is nested within the following code:

[image: Please see highlighted Row]

The below VBA code is my attempt at scraping.  I, perhaps wrongly, feel that I am very close to capturing the value - but the code will not work.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?  It doesn't show an error message but also doesn't output any values.

```
 Sub HousePriceData()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim TxtRng As Range
        Dim ie As Object
        Dim V As Variant
        Dim myValue As Variant

        Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
        ie.NAVIGATE "https://www.hometrack.com/uk/insight/uk-cities-house-price-index/"
        ie.Visible = False

        While ie.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Input") 
        Set TxtRng = ws.Range("C15") 

        Set myValue = ie.document.getElementById("cities-index-table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(7).g‌​etElementsByTagName("td")(5) 

        TxtRng = myValue.innerText 
        End Sub
```

Comment: "the code will not work" - can you elaborate on that?  What does or doesn't happen?  Any error messages?

Comment: Hello Tim, it returns 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch'.  Thanks.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("tbody")(12)` - a table should only have one `body` element. When you have a long line of code like that with multiple places where it could error, it's best to start ebugging by breaking it down into individual lines each of which access only a single element or collection.  Did you mean `getElementsByTagName("tr")(12)` ?

Comment: The below shows no errors but doesn't scrape the data.  I reference `code` tbody `code` as there are tr tags in `code`thead `code` and I thought it appropriate to differentiate between the two?

`code`
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Input")
    Set TxtRng = ws.Range("C15")

    Set myValue = ie.document.getElementById("cities-index-table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(7).getElementsByTagName("td")(5)
    
    TxtRng = myValue.innerText

End Sub `code`

Comment: **update your question** - no-one can read code in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Tim.  Updated code above in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `XHR` and primitive parsing instead of awkward `IE`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim arrTmp As Variant

    strUrl = "https://www.hometrack.com/uk/insight/uk-cities-house-price-index/"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send ""
        strTmp = .ResponseText
    End With
    arrTmp = Split(strTmp, ">London</a></td>", 2)
    strTmp = arrTmp(1)
    arrTmp = Split(strTmp, "<td>", 7)
    strTmp = arrTmp(6)
    arrTmp = Split(strTmp, "</td>", 2)
    strTmp = arrTmp(0)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("C15").Value = strTmp

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes.  This outputs the value 1.2% vs 0.6% (last month London data)?

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
Dim Engmt As String

Engmt = "ERRORHERE"
On Error Resume Next
Engmt = Trim(ie.document.getElementById("cities-index-   table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(12).g‌​etElementsByTagName("td")(4).innerText)
On Error GoTo 0
If Engmt = "ERRORHERE" Then
TxtRng.Value = "ERROR"
Else
TxtRng.Value = Engmt
End If
```